# Tensorflow bazel build doesn't generate .whl file

Tags: python, tensorflow, build, pip, bazel

I'm trying to build tensorflow from sources. I have done so successfully once using the guide on my laptop and now I'm trying on my desktop. The .whl file fails to show up in the /tmp directory, which leads to a failure to install the pip package in the next step. I cannot find the .whl file anywhere. 
I've tried reinstalling bazel and re-downloading the tensorflow git repo
and doing the whole procedure from scratch many times over and it simply fails to show up in /tmp. I don't feel comfortable enough to modify the python package build script to try a different directory.
Can anyone give some advice as to what I can try? (tensorflow installs from pip successfully the usual way).

Invoking the build command after a successful build gives me the following output:

```
WARNING: /home/shagas/Data/SW/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule //tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:gc': No longer supported. Switch to SavedModel immediately.
INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.243s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

But I can't find the .whl anywhere

Answer (score 13):

It seems that I have been missing a step which makes the .whl package out of the build which I thought was intended for another case.

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

Answer (score 0):

If the build succeeds, then Bazel must have built something.

Bazel usually prints the paths of some of the top-level output files at the end of a successful build. The [`--show_outputs=<number>`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/bazel-user-manual.html#flag--show_result) flag sets the limit for the number of paths Bazel prints. If you don't see the built PIP package's path here, you can also look for it under `bazel-bin/path/to/package/*` or `bazel-genfiles/path/to/package/*`.

Comment: I tried searching for the package everywhere already, including the places that you mentioned. I also did a sudo find / -name *tensorflow-1.2.0-py2-none-any.whl and it turns up with nothing.  I can't find any output path towards the end of the bazel build log. I'm going to try launch the bazel build command with the flag that you suggested. 
Also, looking in the /tmp directory I can see hsperfdata directories which are empty. A google search tells me that those are directories made by the jvm.

Comment: The output gives me Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package
INFO: Elapsed time: 1301.838s, Critical Path: 63.01s
INFO: Build completed successfully, 4211 total actions
And no info  as to where the resultant package is.